# How to use Behavior class with Swing events?

Tags: swing, jbutton, behavior, java-3d, wakeup

I'm writing code for a 3D graph, and I want the scene graph to update when the user presses a JButton. I'm trying to use a Behavior class, but I can't find any information on using swing events to wake up the behavior. I would REALLY appreciate any help! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a special behavior object which contains a queue of Runnables. You can then post runnables to the behaviour and wake it up. You will have to sort out proper synchronisation so the behaviour only goes to sleep when there are no more commands in the queue, but it should work.

Make the class into a singleton to be able to run Runnable's inside the BehaviorScheduler, analogous to the SwingUtilities.invokeLater() method.

```
public class ThreadTransferBehavior extends Behavior {
    private final static int POST_ID = 9997;
    private final WakeupOnBehaviorPost m_wakeupPost = new WakeupOnBehaviorPost(this, POST_ID);

    private final Stack<Runnable> commands;


    public synchronized void processStimulus(Enumeration i) {
       while(!commands.isEmpty()) commands.pop().run();
       wakeupOn(m_wakeupPost);
    }

    public synchronized void queueCommand(Runnable r) {
      commands.push(r);
      postId(POST_ID);
    }
}
```